# Access data layer array dynamically in GA4, GTM non e-commerce application

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am trying to track an event for Analytics(non-ecommerce app) in GTM, I want to track data from my data layer for an specific event, where the data is in the form of Array, I want to read that array and show the items in my analytics tool, How can I setup my variable for this?

PS: Not looking for data.items.0, data.items.1, these solution as my array is dynamic and I just want to show all the elements inside my array in GA.

dataLayer : event: 'my-event', data: [{activityName:'activity1'}, {activityName:'activity2'}, {activityName:'activity3'},....]

In Analytics, I want to show the activityName which we receives everytime 'my-event' is fired.

I have found solutions where array elements can be accessed through passing the index in GTM
i.e arr.item.0 etc but I want to do this dynamically

Comment: Please elaborate more on what exactly you mean by dynamically, with examples.